# Unable to find file -lplink

Tags: c, ubuntu

I have been trying to install the plink (https://github.com/insilico/plink). I tried to install it using the following steps.

```
- cloned the repo and went to the directory and ran the following commands
- ./bootstrap.sh
- ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

The terminal gives the following output:

```
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -DUNIX -DWITH_R_PLUGINS -DSKIP -DWITH_LAPACK -fopenmp     -O3   -o plink plink.o -lplink -lgomp -llapack -lz  -ldl -lcrypt 
libtool: link: g++ -DUNIX -DWITH_R_PLUGINS -DSKIP -DWITH_LAPACK -fopenmp -O3 -o plink plink.o  -lplink -lgomp -llapack -lz -ldl -lcrypt -fopenmp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lplink: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code in makefile that contains -lplink is given below:

```
 # dir to install headers for plink library 
libplink_ladir = $(includedir)/plink
 plink_SOURCES = plink.cpp 
plink_LDADD = -lplink
```

Can someone help me understand what exactly is going on here and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone help me understand what exactly is going on here

Their `Makefile.am` is broken -- it expects to find `libplink` somewhere before it has actually built one.

It probably works for developers because they have a *previous* installation of `libplink`, so they never notice the brokenness.

> and how to solve it?

1. You should report this in their bug tracker. Something alongs the lines of "A build on a clean system without previous `plink` installation fails".
2. The real fix is to adjust the `Makefile.am` so it builds `libplink` before trying to link `plink` binary.
3. You *may* be able to work around this problem by running `sudo make install-libLTLIBRARIES && sudo make install`. I can't verify whether that would work because their code fails to even compile with `g++ 12.2.0`.